# perl: append variable to string if it exists

Tags: perl

What I want to do is create a string that, in the middle, has a certain string if a variable evaluates to true, but omits that section if it doesn't.  So I'm trying to do this:

```
my $var1 = "hello";
my $var2 = shift;
my $var3 = "my friend";

if ($var2){
    print "$var1 <$var2> $var3\n";
} else {
    print "$var1 $var3\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ perl test.pl
hello my friend
$ perl test.pl there
hello <there> my friend
```

That is obviously perfectly functional, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do the check inline.  Something like:

```
print "$var1 " . ("<$var2> " if $var2) . "$var3\n";
```

But that gives me a syntax error.  Or If there's a way to do it using substitution within the string, that would be even better.

Comment: `print "$var1 " . ( $var2 ? "<$var2> " : '' ) . "$var3\n";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To `shift` a variable from `@_` and insert it, if it's there

```
print $var1 . (shift // '') . $var2;
```

For example, with a space inserted

```
sub concat {
   my ($var1, $var2) = ("Hello", "Friend");
   print $var1 . (shift // ' ') . $var2, "\n";
}

concat();
concat(" my dear ");
```

There may be questions of design with spaces, please change as suitable. This prints

```
Hello Friend
Hello my dear Friend
```

---

If the angle brackets need be inserted around the variable, with `$var2` already declared

```
print "$var1 " . (defined $var2 ? "<$var2>" : '') . "$var3\n";
```

In a sub, and without declaring an extra variable

```
sub concat {
    my ($var1, $var2) = ("Hello", "Friend");
    print $var1 . (@_ ? ' <' . join(' ', @_) . '> ' : ' ') . $var2, "\n";
}

concat();
concat("my dear");
concat("my", "very", "dear");
```

Prints

```
Hello Friend
Hello <my dear> Friend
Hello <my very dear> Friend
```

Again, change the handling of spaces as suitable for the application.

---

You can also use `substr` conditionally on an existing string but that is more cumbersome.

Comment: could this handle the angle brackets? i.e. could it print `"hello <there> my friend"` or `"hello my friend"`? smartly either including or excluding the `<>`?

Comment: @ewok  Right, I was going to ask about those angle brackets -- do you mean like literal characters?  (Or ... reading from some filehandle?)

Comment: literal characters.  I want the angle brackets to be in the printed string if `$var2` evaluates to true and omitted otherwise

Comment: @ewok Right, I see.  I missed that.  I'm going to add.

Comment: @ewok Posted, is this good enough? I'm thinking through something more concise.

Comment: @ewok  I added another example, which may (or may not) be useful, please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to sanitize your variables as they come in, but if you are importing a lot, it may be cleaner to grep the arguments or variable list for those that are *defined*, which filters out those that have no value.  Then you can join those with your spaces.

## [CodePad](http://codepad.org/LDdWhH4B)

```
sub format_input{
   map{qq{<$_>}} @_;
}

sub func {
   my $var1 = "hello";
   my $var2 = "my friend";
   my @arr  = format_input grep{defined and length} @_;
   my $string = join ' ', $var1, @arr, $var2;
   print qq{$string\n};
}

func("there");           # hello <there> my friend
func('foo','bar');       # hello <foo> <bar> my friend
func('foo',undef,'bar'); # hello <foo> <bar> my friend
func('foo','','bar');    # hello <foo> <bar> my friend
func();                  # hello my friend
```

In place of `{defined}`, you could do something like `{/[\w\d]/}` to make sure there was a letter or digit passed in, which should take care of most blank string issues.  You could also implement a *trim* and look at *length* or some other metric to sanitize your input -- whatever best communicates your need.

---

***Edit:***
Because there could be more extensive formatting, the above created a separate subroutine, but it could have just as easily been coded as `my @arr = map{"<$_>"} grep {defined and length} @_;` with no `sub format_input...` used at all.

Comment: how could this be enhanced to handle the angle brackets?  I don't just want `"hello there my friend"` I want `"hello <there> my friend"`

Comment: @ewok final edit to show sanitizing before formatting to take undefined and blank string inputs into consideration; if blank strings should be represented as `<>`, then remove the *`and length`* from the grep condition.